# Rule that checks if a class uses a method in a group of classes

Tags: java, pmd

I'm trying to write a xpath-rule where I'd like to warn about using a couple of methods given a specific namespace. The rule could be stated as:

*You should only be able to call create/update/delete in classes named with suffix Repository if the call is made from a class named with suffix domain.*

The part where I fail is how to connect the field "private XXXRepository xxxRepository" to the call "xxxRepository.create()" in a method later in the code. Just checking that the the case where the naming convension is followed seems insufficent.

Example code:

```
public class Example()
  private TestRepository testRepository;

  public void callToCreate(){
    testRepository.create();
  }
}
```

Comment: You mention xpath but it seems like you are validating java code, not xml?

Comment: Lance, the definition of the test is written as an xpath-expression. PMD uses that xpath-expression to validate the contents of the java-class.